# Unknown column in 'field list' in MariaDB query

Tags: sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I'm trying to rewrite these SQL queries into JPQL:

```
SELECT  `payment_transactions`.* 
FROM `payment_transactions` 
INNER JOIN `wpf_payment_payment_transactions` 
    ON `payment_transactions`.`id` = `wpf_payment_payment_transactions`.`payment_transaction_id` 
WHERE `wpf_payment_payment_transactions`.`wpf_payment_id` = 75  
ORDER BY `payment_transactions`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT 1


SELECT `payment_transactions`.* 
FROM `payment_transactions` 
INNER JOIN `wpf_payment_payment_transactions` 
    ON `payment_transactions`.`id` = `wpf_payment_payment_transactions`.`payment_transaction_id` 
WHERE `wpf_payment_payment_transactions`.`wpf_payment_id` = 75
```

I tried to implement this:

```
SELECT t 
FROM payment_transactions t 
INNER JOIN wpf_payment_payment_transactions wppt 
    ON t.id = wppt.payment_transaction_id
WHERE wppt.wpf_payment_id = 1 
ORDER BY t.id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

But I get error:

> Unknown column 't' in 'field list'

Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use * for select all the columns:

In your case you should use:

```
SELECT t.* from...
```